# BigO of Vector using Iterator

Tags: java, vector, big-o

I've made some researches but I didn't find a good article.
I am adding multiple `Vectors` to one `Vector`, after that I am printing it:

```
Iterator it =vector.iterator();
    while(it.hasNext()){
        System.out.println(it.next());
    }
```

How do I determine the Big-O notation for this function?
For example if the output were:

> [Something, Something, Something, Something]
>  [Something,
>   Something, Something, Something, Something]
>  [Something,
>   Something, Something, Something, Something, Something]
>   [Something, Something, Something, Something, Something, Something,
>   Something]
>  [Something, Something, Something, Something,
>   Something, Something, Something, Something]

And what I am not understanding each line is a vector, for the main vector we need a loop, but for the vectors inside it we don't need a loop, Why ?

Comment: `O(n)` with `n` being the size of your vector. Simple as that.

Comment: The question is a bit unclear. if you want to big O notation of your print, you just have to look at the number of operations you are performing. Say there are N elements in your vector, your printout will have O(N) as asymptotic equivalence ( which is big O notation.)

Comment: what about the other vectors inside the main one ?

Answer (score 2):

When you call `toString` on a collection (like a `Vector`), you get a comma separated list, enclosed by square brackets, of the `toString` of every element in that collection.

So, what your code is doing is calling `toString` on every `Vector` in your main `Vector` which in turn calls `toString` on every element.  So the efficiency is O(n) where n is the total number of objects upon which `toString` is being called.

Comment: So every `vector.get(i)` will returns element in that index.`toString()` ?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you allways follow this "ladder pattern":

If the size of the first vector is 1, and the size of the last vector is K, using summation formulas, the complexity is:

```
K*(K+1)/2
```

Now, if the size of the first vector is k < K, we have:

```
K(K+1)/2 - (k-1)(k)/2
```

Finally, if we dont have the "ladder pattern" but N vectors of size < K, the complexity is:

```
K*N
```

Hope it helps.